# Spring - PropertyOverrideConfigurer multiple configuration lines for ONE bean property

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring xml file with some beans, two of which I have pasted below:

```
<bean 
     class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer">
      <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:projectname-override.properties</value>
      </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myBeanName"
      class="my.company.department.svc.spring.WmSvcJndiDataSource">
  <property name="jndiName">
    <value>jdbc/XXXXX</value>
  </property>
  <property name="jndiTemplate">
    <ref bean="myJndiTemplate" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

The properties file referred to in the first bean is very small (currently only one line), and looks like this:

```
myBeanName.jndiName=java:comp/env/jdbc/XXXXX_YYY_DEV3
```

It is my understanding that [PropertyOverrideConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyOverrideConfigurer.html) in the first bean

> pushes values from a properties file into bean definitions

So the value of the **jndiName** property in the **myBeanName** bean will turn from

`jdbc/XXXXX`

to

`java:comp/env/jdbc/XXXXX_YYY_DEV3`.

This works and it partially does what we want.  **I need to expand the functionality so that I can handle *multiple* deployment environments.**  This currently replaces the bean property for one of our development environments (dev3).  I think I need spring to dynamically alter "myBeanName" for about 25 different dev environments.

For example, I think I want my properties file to look like this

```
myBeanName.jndiName=java:comp/env/jdbc/XXXXX_YYY_DEV1
myBeanName.jndiName=java:comp/env/jdbc/XXXXX_YYY_DEV2
myBeanName.jndiName=java:comp/env/jdbc/XXXXX_YYY_DEV3
myBeanName.jndiName=java:comp/env/jdbc/XXXXX_YYY_DEV4
myBeanName.jndiName=java:comp/env/jdbc/XXXXX_YYY_DEV5
    ...
    ...
myBeanName.jndiName=java:comp/env/jdbc/XXXXX_YYY_DEV24
myBeanName.jndiName=java:comp/env/jdbc/XXXXX_YYY_DEV25
```

I have no idea if this is the right approach.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE**

`my.company.department.svc.spring.WmSvcJndiDataSource` in the second bean is simply a class we extended off of `org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean`, FYI.  I don't know if that is important to know or not.

Comment: Read the doc about environment?

Comment: @RC. your comment would be more helpful if you provided the link

Comment: I was looking for it :) http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

Comment: So, first thing you realize is that this approach will not work because `Properties` extends `Map` so if there are multiple values with the same key, only the last one will be retained. No in this case the only value retained is `myBeanName.jndiName=java:comp/env/jdbc/XXXXX_YYY_DEV25`

Comment: @JohnB OK, that makes sense.  I posted that as an example of what I would like to do... how then can I emulate that behavior?

Comment: @RC. I'll check out the link, thanks.